# Displaying images of attributes Woocommerce/Taxonomy Images plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce, taxonomy

I need to get images attached to color attribute in current product and insert it into separate css styled gallery of colors on single product site.

I am adding color attributes to products in **Woocommerce** (I am creating my own theme in Wordpress), adding images of the textures of colors to these attributes by the [**Taxonomy Image plugin**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/)
and want to display these images on single product site.

Trying to add:`$result = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-queried-term-image', '' );`
in content-single-product.php, but it gives me nothing.

I also tried other ways, that I found on the Internet and this page, and I cannot display these images. Or there is different, better way to reach and display them? (with WooCommerce, without Taxonomy Image plugin).

[image: What I want to achieve]

Comment: I solve it in different way: with Advanced Custom Fields, adding Gallery.